# Is pecl extension php-amqp cause memory leaking?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

Lets imagine we have to create exchanges and queues. First script will use pecl extension

pastebin.com/2vzQBjtQ

Second script will use php-aqmp library http://github.com/videlalvaro/php-amqplib

pastebin.com/WurFfDSE

Scripts are same, they just declare exchanges and queues through loop and demonstrate system memory.

Run first script, we get

```
php /home/www/application/controllers/rabbit_memory_test.php
100 Memory usage is 23277568
200 Memory usage is 39096320
300 Memory usage is 56262656
400 Memory usage is 74784768
500 Memory usage is 94380032
600 Memory usage is 115019776
700 Memory usage is 135467008
800 Memory usage is 156147712
900 Memory usage is 177041408
It took 2.9051361083984 seconds for php.
```

Run second script, we get

```
php /home/www/application/controllers/rabbit_memory_test2.php
100 Memory usage is 9306112
200 Memory usage is 9342976
300 Memory usage is 9342976
400 Memory usage is 9342976
500 Memory usage is 9342976
600 Memory usage is 9342976
700 Memory usage is 9342976
800 Memory usage is 9342976
900 Memory usage is 9342976
1000 Memory usage is 9342976
It took 2.7014260292053 seconds for php.
```

Is it memory leak while using pecl extension or i am using extension api in wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem, move this code of the 1st script to the begin of the loop

```
$connection = new AMQPConnection();
$connection->connect();

// Open Channel
$channel    = new AMQPChannel($connection);
$exchange   = new AMQPExchange($channel);
$queue      = new AMQPQueue($channel);
```